# vb.net Runtime Objects and creating an actual variable

Tags: vb.net, oop, textbox, runtime

hi im my current system im creating i have a label factory a button factory and a textbox factory, they all work well and allocated diffrent addresses and locations, 
However because it is not done the conventonal "Dim button1 as button" i cannot call for a task in another sub is there any way around this, inorder to make it an actual variable that i can use,thanks. also sorry for my post format still a bit unsure of how to properly structure my questions.

```
Private Sub CreateTxtTypeBox(ByVal BoxTypes As BoxType, ByVal Boxname As String, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal AllowDrop As Boolean, ByVal DropDI As Integer, ByVal TextHandler As System.EventHandler)

    Select Case BoxTypes

        Case BoxType.Combo_box

            Dim box As ComboBox = New ComboBox
            With box
                .Name = Boxname
                .Size = New Size(width, height)
                .Location = New Point(x, y)
                .AllowDrop() = AllowDrop
                .MaxDropDownItems = DropDI
                .Enabled = True
                Controls.Add(box)
                AddHandler box.TextChanged, TextHandler

            End With

        Case BoxType.Txt_box

            Dim box As TextBox = New TextBox
            With box
                .Name = Boxname
                .Size = New Size(width, height)
                .Location = New Point(x, y)
                Controls.Add(box)
                AddHandler box.TextChanged, TextHandler
            End With

    End Select

End Sub
```

an example of one of the statements i run into my boxtype factory

```
CreateTxtTypeBox(BoxType.Combo_box, "CSearch_Box", 90, 
      20, 190, 240, True, 5, AddressOf CsearchBoxHandler_textchanged)
```

---

```
Private Sub CsearchBoxHandler_textchanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,
             ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' converts the sender value of the text box into a sutable string format'
    Dim TBtext As String = CType(sender, ComboBox).Text
    Dim returnVal As String
    Dim searchCust As SearchCustomers = New SearchCustomers

    searchCust.Csearch(TBtext)

    returnVal = searchCust.Csearch(TBtext)

    If Not returnVal = "" Then

        If Not Csearch.Items.Contains(returnVal) Then
            Csearch.Items.Add(returnVal)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

this is where the actual issue lies , the Csearch is not declared and cannot be used

Comment: I think you've made it more complex that it needs to be.  `CreateTxtTypeBox` violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and takes so many args that it is just as easy to create a TB or CBO rather than call that thing.  That should resolve the event handler as well.

Comment: would this method be worth doing on a larger scale system when i need to create round 100 text boxes at diffrent times ?

Comment: split it into 2 **functions** would simplify things.  TB then just requires `h,w,x,y` the caller then hooks up the event handler(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a global variable :

```
dim ConstrolsList as list(of control)
```

And inside the method CreateTxtTypeBox, you add :

```
ControlsList.add(Box)
```

This way, you will have the list of the controls you created. Otherwise, you can have access to the controls created using Me.Controls but it's more complicated to get the control you need.